# Extern Configuration in spring app

Tags: spring, tomcat, configuration

I have 10 the same application on my Tomcat Server and I want to get diffrent configuration for then (credentials for DB and other params), each configuration will be stored in other file - becouse it will be boring and taking too much time to pass this params manually and then deploy app.

How to easly achive this ? Maybe sth what rely on first initialization url ?

Comment: Make your life easier and deploy your 10 applications in 10 different tomcats. Or use containers like docker.

Comment: What that change ?

Comment: You could configure every instance on your own with specific properties.

Comment: hmm its good solution, but I think that will be to heavy for my VPS. Du u know other way ? ;)